# MySQL index doesn't work right in join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm doing join from two tables of different databases:

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    `db1`.`view1` p
    join
    `db2`.`table1` e
            on e.Migration = p.s_encargo  and e.did=149;
```

I made a index in table1 like this:

```
alter table table1 add INDEX `DID_Migration` (`DID`, `Migration`);
```

I added the two fields I used in on clause, in the index ('did' and 'migration')

But when i execute the query, only used the first column of the index (did):
[image]
This is the explain of the query.

But if I show the explain of the this other query:

```
select * from table1 where  Migration = '100008600' and did=149;
```

this use all columns of index:
[image]

Why in the first query only use the first column of the index, and in the second query uses the two columns?

Comment: can you provide table structure DDL (column types and constraints)?

Comment: Please give us information on table1: How many rows in it? How many rows per `Migration` (min/max/avg)? How many rows for `DID = 149`?

Comment: DID=149 have 5435 rows. Table1 have 96003 rows. Migration is the ID of another table, the combination DID and Migration should be unique

Comment: `DID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `Migration` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 
 Without any constraint whit this columns

Comment: 96003 rows is not much and quickly read. 5435 is more than 5% of that. Have you tested whether using the index is even faster than a mere full table scan? It may well be that it is slower. This is why I am asking about the `Migration` column. How many records will I usually find for one `Migration`? If that's less than 5435, an index with changed positions (`Migration` first `DID` second) might be more appropriate

Comment: I've tried to use the reverse index, and a single migration index, but it's not even on the list of candidate indexes. It is as if the migration column cannot use index.

Comment: ... or the DBMS - as mentioned - doesn't want to use it. Reading 96003 rows sequentielly from a table can be way faster than reading 5000 (or even just 500) via an index. The DBMS decides against an index and you want to tell it to use it, though. Maybe you shouldn't.

Comment: Maybe read 90.000 rows is faster, but the query is a select from a view with 20.000 rows and avery row join with a table 1 (with index have 3000 rows to check) and join with table2 (with index have 5400 rows candidates). I tried execute with and without this indexes and it take hours and no finish. I need use the index of migracion.

Answer (score 0):

The key_len column indicates the length of the key that MySQL decided to use. 
  The value of key_len enables you to determine how many parts of a multiple-part key MySQL actually uses.

This mean that for the query you declared  mysql choose to use only the first part

in this case you can use force (or use)  for impose the index  you want

```
    SELECT
        count(*)
    FROM
        `db1`.`view1` p
        join
        `db2`.`table1` e FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (`DID_Migration`)
                    on e.Migration = p.s_encargo  and e.did=149;
```

Comment: I've just tested it, but it still uses the same index, it only uses the first column of the index, not the whole index.
The first table of the join is not a table but a view of several tables. I don't know if that'll be a problem.

Comment: If in the query, on the on clause change p.s_encargo with '1094723' for example, this work fine, use the full index, like the second query.

Comment: The index  used is always  DID_migration in your explain plan .. the problem is that use only the first part of the keys    .. so you could try inverting the keys if you need  all match  ... remember that the DID part/key is the most selective and this could reduce the cardinality to a low level that the query optimizer thinks is  optimal